# How to match id's in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables in my database, one with some userinfo (**usersTable**) and another one with submissions (**submissionsTable**).

usersTable has an pk usersId, so everytime someone registers they get a certain Id.

When a registered person submits something, the submission goes to **submissionsTable**. I put a usersId in **submissionsTable** that I would like to match with the usersId from **usersTable**. So for example everytime someone with usersTable.usersId = 15 submits something, I want **submissionsTable**.usersId to be automatically 15. I have no idea how, I'm stuck.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You'll need some way of getting the usersID from the usersTable before inserting the new row into submissionsTable, to get all of the user's submissions you'd use the Join operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreign key concept. Add this to your table description:

`foreign key (submissionsTable.usersId) references usertable (usersTable.usersId)`

You can also add `on delete cascade` at the end, so that when a user is deleted its submission data is also deleted.

if you are altering an existing table:

`ALTER TABLE submissionsTable ADD FOREIGN KEY submissionsTable(usersId) REFERENCES usersTable(usersId) ON DELETE CASCADE`

After this, your submissionsTable will be taking only the valid values from usersTable. But still, you will have to run a query to store that value in you database.

Comment: Then I get this error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'foreign key (submissionsTable.usersId) references usersTable (usersTable.usersId)' at line 1

Comment: Did you **add** it to your table description ? Probably not. Read the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

Comment: And yes...sorry..I forgot to mention if you have an existing table you will have to alter the table

Comment: My pleasure...would you please mark my solution as the answer.. :)

Comment: grrr i can see to figure out the query.. any help? sorry im a new  to php and mysql

Comment: what is that you want to execute...?

Comment: When a registered person submits something, submissionsTable.usersId has to be the same as usersTable.usersId

When I try to submit something, I get this error
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projectwebsite`.`submissions`, CONSTRAINT `submissions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`usersId`) REFERENCES `usersTable` (`usersId`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Comment: Its likely that your table submissionTable already contains some data that doesn't exists in the userTable. Check for those value...and remove them and then try again...